# Vim doesn't keep keep the same indentation as the line above it only in one situation

Tags: indentation, alignment

```
fn main {
    scores.entry(team_1_name)
        .and_modify(|&mut team| {
            team.goals_scored += team_1_score;
            team.goals_conceded += team_2_score;
        })
}
```

When I press <Enter> after the closing parentheses for the `.and_modify()` call, my cursor aligns with `scores` rather than the `.and_modify()`.

Furthermore, when I manually tab the next method call like this:

```
fn main() {
    scores.entry(team_1_name)
        .and_modify(|&mut team| {
            team.goals_scored += team_1_score;
            team.goals_conceded += team_2_score;
        }) 
        .or_insert( Team {} )
}
```

As soon as I hit <Enter> in between the `{}` to begin populating the fields of this struct on a new line, the entire line gets unindented to align with `scores` again.

1. How can I tell Vim to respect the existing indentation?
2. Is it possible to have the `.and_modify()` align with the `.entry` of the line above it?

Edit: setting autoindent and smartindent did not resolve this issue

Comment: Could you tell us what is the type of your buffer? What is the result of the `:set ft?` command? From the content of the buffer it looks like `rust` but I would like you to confirm.

Comment: I can reproduce your problem and it looks to me a flaw in `GetRustIndent()` used by `indentexpr`. I don't know Rust enough to know you to improve it.

Comment: I would let the folks at https://github.com/rust-lang/rust.vim know

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt when I run `:set ft` I get `filetype=rust`. I am using rust-analyzer with https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim. I'm a bit new to how these things work, would this be connected to the rust.vim repo?

Comment: What is the result of `set indentexpr?`?

Comment: As I already said I suspect you are in a corner case of indentexpr :-/

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt the result of `set indentexpr` is `indentexpr=GetRustIndent(v:lnum)`

Comment: Thanks, like I said I suppose that function: `GetRustIndent` need to be fixed :-/

Comment: Gotcha, thank you for the insight :-)